# Batch File. Copying user profile to flash drive

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that would automate a process for our business. We lease our computers. We are trying to write a batch file on a thumb drive. We want to plug the thumb drive in and copy the users Documents,Favorites,Pictures,etc. I have been successful in writing the code to name the file and create the sub folders. However, I am falling short on copying the files.

Here is my code..any help is appreciated.

```
SET initDir=D:\
SET newDir=
SET /P newDir=Type folder name: %=%

IF DEFINED newDir (
    MD D:\%newDir%
    SET initDir=%initDir%\%newDir%
)

MD "D:\%newDir%\Desktop"
MD "D:\%newDir%\Documents"
MD "D:\%newDir%\Music"
MD "D:\%newDir%\Pictures"
MD "D:\%newDir%\Favorites"
MD "D:\%newDir%\Links"

copy "C:\Users\%userprofile%\Pictures\" * "D:\%newDir%\Pictures"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xcopy.exe is the solution here. It's built into Windows.

```
xcopy /s  c:\Folder1 d:\Folder2
```

You can find more options at http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm

### Update:

To copy all the files and subdirectories (including any empty subdirectories) from drive A to drive B, type:

```
xcopy /s /e c:\Folder1 d:\Folder2
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have it copying some files but not all files now. Now that it is copying folders, it is not creating some subfolders that are in the section of code right before the backup

Comment: SET initDir=D:\
SET newDir=
SET /P newDir=Type folder name: %=%

IF DEFINED newDir (
 MD D:\%newDir%
 SET initDir=%initDir%\%newDir%
)
 
MD "D:\%newDir%\Desktop"
MD "D:\%newDir%\Documents"
MD "D:\%newDir%\Music"
MD "D:\%newDir%\Pictures"
MD "D:\%newDir%\Favorites"
MD "D:\%newDir%\Links"

#Echo Copying

set backupcmd=xcopy /c
xcopy /c "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" "D:\%newDir%\Desktop"
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" "D:\%newDir%\Documents" 
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Music" "D:\%newDir%\Music" 
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Pictures" "D:\%newDir%\Pictures"

Comment: Maybe this will help you  - To copy all the files and subdirectories (including any empty subdirectories) from drive A to drive B, type:

xcopy a: b: /s /e

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much.